# Aligning Equations in LaTeX

Tags: algorithms, math-mode

I was trying to align the following equations but alas. Could someone guide?

```
\begin{flalign}
x \in A \cap (B \cup C)
& \Rightarrow (x \in A) \lambda \Big( (x \in B)\vee(x \in C) \Big) & \\
& \Rightarrow \Big( (x \in A) \lambda (x \in B) \Big) \vee \Big( (x \in A) \lambda (x \in C) \Big) & \\
& \Rightarrow (x \in A \cap B) \lambda ( x \in A \cap C) & \\
& \Rightarrow x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) 
\end{flalign}
```

to look like

```
a => b
  => c
  => d
  => e
```

Here's the preamble that I used:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\title{Basic Typesetting of Mathematics}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
```

I am using Texmaker and it's not recognising `\begin{flalign*}` or `\end{flalign*}`. Gives weird compilation errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is compiling just fine.

I've made the parentheses a bit smaller and used the left/right versions of them to get better horizontal spacing. Also, there were unnecessary ampersands.

Version 1:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
x \in A \cap (B \cup C)
&\Rightarrow (x \in A) \lambda \bigl((x \in B) \vee (x \in C)\bigr)\\
&\Rightarrow \bigl((x \in A) \lambda (x \in B)\bigr) \vee \bigl((x \in A) \lambda (x \in C)\bigr)\\
&\Rightarrow (x \in A \cap B) \lambda (x \in A \cap C)\\
&\Rightarrow x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) 
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

Version 2: Using daleif's suggestion from the comment to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161611/15874), you get

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}

\newcommand*\implic{\quad\Rightarrow\quad}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
x \in A \cap (B \cup C)
&\implic  (x \in A) \lambda \bigl((x \in B) \vee (x \in C)\bigr)\\
&\implic \bigl((x \in A) \lambda (x \in B)\bigr) \vee \bigl((x \in A) \lambda (x \in C)\bigr)\\
&\implic (x \in A \cap B) \lambda (x \in A \cap C)\\
&\implic x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) 
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Answer (score 3):

This code works.
I removed big brackets to have the same space between equations

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
     x \in A \cap (B \cup C)
        & \Rightarrow (x \in A) \lambda \left( (x \in B)\vee(x \in C) \right) & \\
        & \Rightarrow \left( (x \in A) \lambda (x \in B) \right) \vee \left( (x \in A)\lambda (x \in C) \right) & \\
        & \Rightarrow (x \in A \cap B) \lambda ( x \in A \cap C) & \\
        & \Rightarrow x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) 
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Abi: the best way to thank others is not saying +1, but rather upvoting the answers and accepting the best one; have a look to [TeX.SX tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Oh @ClaudioFiandrino I had less reputation :P here so wanted to thank anyways regardless of that.. But now I did.. Thank you again :*

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
 x \in A \cap (B \cup C)
  & \Rightarrow (x \in A) \lambda \Big( (x \in B)\vee(x \in C) \Big) & \\
  & \Rightarrow \Big( (x \in A) \lambda (x \in B) \Big) \vee \Big( (x \in A)\lambda (x \in C) \Big) & \\
  & \Rightarrow (x \in A \cap B) \lambda ( x \in A \cap C) & \\
  & \Rightarrow x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) 
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you !! It works perfectly the way I wanted :) +++1

Comment: Might look better if you added extra space around the `\Rightarrow`, I usually use `\Rightarrowx` as a short for `\quad\Rightarrow\quad`